# how to printf a dynamic amount of placeholders in c?

Tags: c, printf, d, placeholder, digits

Normally you have a set amount of placeholders in your printf(), which means I'd have to decide on a set amount of digit and string placeholders in advance.

Is it possible to make the amount of placeholders in your printf() dynamic or make specifically %d placeholders print an "empty" char

Comment: what if i have multiple of these next to each other ? does it matter what that the "width" variable is named? or does the compiler just assume the variable in front of "value" is the the "width" variable ?

Comment: @Pingu The _run-time_ (not the compiler) just takes "the next thing" from the parameter list when it finds `%*` and uses it as the width. So `printf( "%d %d", a, b )` will print two numbers using the default width, `printf( "%d %*d", a, widthB, b )` will print `a` normally, then use `widthB` (the next parameter) as the width for printing `b`. `printf( "%*d %*d", widthA, a, widthB, b )` will use a (separate) width for both `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("%*.*d", width, precision, value);
```

Using this format you can keep the width and precision flexible and feed them to the `printf`.

Consider the following example:

```
printf("<%*.*d>\n", 4, 1, 12);
printf("<%-*.*d>\n", 4, 3, 12);
printf("<%*.*d>\n", 0, 0, 0);
printf("<%*.*d>\n", 2, 0, 0);
```

Output:

```
<  12>                                                                                                                                                                   
<012 >                                                                                                                                                                   
<>
<  >
```

Comment: What i am looking for is a some kind of width value that simply makes the value "invisible" i was hoping that width = 0 would print "nothing"
<  >

Comment: @Pingu So you want to _conditionally_ print values, not specifically control the width (which is what "_amount of digits_" make it sound like you were asking)? Off the top of my head, I don't remember there being a "conditional print" option (at least in the standard version of `printf` ... it _possible_ someone may have written a non-standard extension).

Comment: yeah, specifically i want to avoid printing the placeholder if the value = 0, but i still need the placeholder inside the printf() in case the value != 0

Comment: @Pingu, If this is the case then you need to put `precision = 0`, Please check the updated answer